# rm -rf cannot remove some folders on xfs system

Tags: linux

The nas is running on a cut down version of debian. I've ssh onto the box and ran rm -rf of their directory

rm: cannot remove 'lfamb32/backup-11-07-2013 - bits/Local Disk (C)/New Volume (D) - Lamb files/Backup': Directory not empty

There are hundreds of directory on it. What can I do? I'm running the commands as root.

Edit: Showing io errors in dmesg. Guess the hard drive is failing!

Comment: Is there any difference if you use `rm -r -f` or `rm -R` ?

Comment: I think there is a hardware fault on the NAS. Showing IO errors on dmesg. No wonder...

Comment: @Ibanz might be a good idea to update your question with that, or if you accept it, answer the question yourself with your finding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran xfs_repair and turns out there is a hardware fault. Dmesg also shows it. Relaced disk and recover from backup now I'm able to delete the files.